# Google MAP help

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay, tagging

I have a map in my app, and I want to click a random place on the map and

- Get the longitude and latitude of the location and use that information in my app
- Use that longitude and latitude to get either the address of a location that is nearby
- Find things that are near that location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what's nearby you can use google's reverse GeoCoding -> [Reverse GeoCoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

And to convert coordinates to pixels and vice versa
take a look at projections and GeoPoints

Here's an example

```
        GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        projection.toPixels(gP1, point);
```